# fileExistsAtPath: Does Not Return Correct Value in iOS 8 SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, nsfilemanager, file-exists

My app was working perfectly in iOS 7, and now I'm facing some new bugs after switching to iOS 8 SDK.

For Ex. `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` file existence checking method ( `fileExistsAtPath:` ) is no longer working. Here's the details about current situation in my code:

1. This is the block of code whose condition never turns `True` :

   ```
   File *tempFile = currentMessage.contains;
   NSString *address = tempFile.thumbAddress;

   if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:currentMessage.contains.thumbAddress])
   {
       image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:currentMessage.contains.thumbAddress];
   }
   ```
2. I have put a breakpoint before the if and traced it to see what is contains :

   ```
   Printing description of address:
   /Users/Unkn0wn/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C07E1D76-372E-4C9A-8749-50D369294FBA/data/Containers/Data/Application/1DC7DB3A-B0A2-43AE-9EDA-3E121786D1AA/Documents/FileAt141406917489510096thumbnail.jpg
   ```
3. I have checked the Finder to see if the file actually exists ( the address is copied from console so there's no chance of mistyping and typos in checking the path and file existence ) :

[image]

But that `if` block is not executed because `fileExistsAtPath:` returns `NO`.

Am I missing anything or it is just a bug of new SDK ? ( Because it was working perfectly with SDK 7.1.1 )

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try calling `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:address];` without checking `fileExistsAtPath:`, do you get `nil` or you get your image data? If you get `nil`, you probably have an incorrect path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `thumbAddress` is a full path (not a relative one), it can cause bugs when the app is updated because the app folder changes, for example, your first version of the app could be at that path:

```
/Users/Unkn0wn/Library/Developer/.../Application/ABCD/
```

When you update the app, the directory will change, for example:

```
/Users/Unkn0wn/Library/Developer/.../Application/EFGH/
```

So if you save a full path for your image in the first version of the app like :

```
ABCD/yourImage.jpg
```

And try to retrieve this image with the new version of the app, this image will not be found anymore as your image will now be at the path:

```
EFGH/yourImage.jpg
```

Hopes it helps!

---

**EDIT**

Maybe your absolute path is incorrect. Try calling it with a relative path:

```
NSString *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
path = [path stringByAppendingString:@"FileAt141406917489510096thumbnail.jpg"];

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]; // Should be != nil
```

Comment: This could also be a permissions issue. If it exists, but the folder cannot be read, it won't be found.

Comment: I'm talking about a single version, It's not about updating the app !

Comment: Yes, Apparently it's not only about version upgrades in iOS 8, but also about launching app for another time !